# What is wrong with my UPDATE statement?

Tags: sql

I just want to update the status of a booking using bookingid.

```
UPDATE flightbooking
SET status 'C' AS cancelledbooking
FROM flightbooking
WHERE bookingid = 10001;
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'C'"
>    LINE 2: SET status 'C' AS cancelledbooking

Any help?

Comment: `AS` is aliasing in SELECT context, not UPDATE.

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest:

```
UPDATE flightbooking
    SET status = 'C'
    WHERE bookingid = 10001;
```

This should work in any database, assuming you have the right table and columns.

`FROM` is not part of the `FROM` clause necessarily.  In addition, how it gets interpreted varies among databases.  Once you fix the `SET` clause, Postgres would update all rows (I think); SQL Server would update the matching row; Oracle and MySQL would generate an error.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use an alias within an update statement.

```
UPDATE flightbooking
SET status = 'C'
FROM flightbooking
WHERE bookingid = 10001;
```

Answer (score 0):

AS is used for aliasing in SELECT context, not UPDATE.

This will work:

```
UPDATE flightbooking
SET status = 'C'
FROM flightbooking
WHERE bookingid = 10001;
```

Comment: It says  flightbooking is specified more than once, do i just give it a different name in either update or from?

Comment: Can you share your table schema please?

Comment: Cool, happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
UPDATE flightbooking SET status = 'C' WHERE bookingid = 10001
```